# i want to login as an admin and as user in same browser in different tabs , how it is possible?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I am creating an app where I need functionality like this.
using role and permission in this app.

problem:

whenever the admin clicks on the logout button on their tab the user also logout from a different tab.
I try to fetch logged user details by using `<Auth::user()` in both, and it returns the same results,
and the result is that it only shows the admin details, not shows the user(role) details.

I tried to solve this issue using middleware and session but did not work, another way I tried to solve this using
multiple AUTH systems.

Comment: Two browser tabs will usually share the same session, so you can't be logged in twice to the same application in the same browser. Better maybe to give one user multiple roles so they can do both admin tasks and other tasks from the same user account

Comment: you can't log in to both with the same session. try different sessions like admin session and user session.

Comment: Or, if the users must be separate, try logging in from a different browser, or from a private browsing session. Some browsers may also have features which allow you to start a separate window with a new session, you'd have to check with whatever browsers you use

Comment: @M.Haris already tried that way

Comment: @ADyson thanks for response but different browser is not my solution , i want to use in same browser

Comment: Why are you wanting/needing the ability for two separate user's to be authenticated in the same browser?

Comment: @Rwd  because i must have to provide a  functionality like this.

Comment: Then you should use a role-based approach in your application instead of having different users for different abilities. Then you can give one user two different roles for access to admin and regular functionality

Comment: Well, did you try to create a new `guard` in `config/auth.php` ?

Comment: @xenooooo yes i already tried it.

Comment: Did you specify which guard do you want to logout in your controller ? `User::guard('admin')->logout()` ?

Comment: @xenooooo No but i try that way

Answer (score -1):

This might not be what you want, but if you are coding the login/authentication stuff yourself you can customise it as you like. You could put something like loginid=eytuuytytuytuytutytute on all the links and forms etc. so that your application knows what user login to associate with the session. This is probably ill advised though. It would be safer and easier to just toggle to another browser.